# Select radio group by one child's class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can i select whole radio group if i only know one of it's inputs name?

IE:

```
<input type="radio" class="expand-trigger" name="r01" />
<input type="radio" name="r01" />
```

If i click on .expand-trigger, the "change" event happens and , lets say, something expands. But if i click on another input in the same group, the change event does not trigger for .expand-trigger, therefore i cannot collaps expanded element.

So what i wanna do is to attach change event to all inputs that are in same group as .expand-trigger, but cant figure out how and im not even sure it will work.

Rememeber -- radio's name attribute changes and i have no control over it, i only can add class to one of its children.

It's really bad that no event will trigger if element that is checked will be checked because other element got checked...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can get the name:

```
var name = $('.expand-trigger').attr('name');
```

and then select the others:

```
$('input[name="' + name + '"]').change(...
```

Comment: Thanks! works atm but if there are more radio groups with .expand-trigger, were in deep :)

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the radio buttons inside a container, you can use siblings():

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="expand-trigger" name="r01" />
    <input type="radio" name="r01" />
</div>

var $RadioButton  = $(".expand-trigger").css('background-color', 'red');
$RadioButton.siblings().css('background-color', 'red');
```